# Expected value exercise $E[e^{-\mu Y}]$

Tags: probability, statistics

Exercise:

Let $X_i\sim Exp(\lambda_i), \,\,i\in[1,3]$. With each $X_i$ independent.
In addition let $Y = \min\{X_i\}$ and $\mu \in \Re$.

Calculate: $E[e^{-\mu Y}]$

I honestly have no idea where to start, maybe because of the summer hollidays. Can someone please help me with this problem?
(I can't figure out for example what distribution $Y$ has.)

Comment: As far as I know, minimum of independent exponential distributions is again exponential with parameter equal to sum of their parameters. If I'm not mistaken this was in wiki. You can check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\Pr(Y>y)=\Pr(X_1>y\wedge X_2>y\wedge X_3>y)$$

Work this out (use independence) in order to find the distribution of $Y$.